# Checking check boxes based on a condition - WPF

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I am getting data for checkboxes from database.

```
<stackPanel Name="StudentDetails">
  <checkBox Name="Left" Content="(M)" Unchecked="CheckBoxUnChecked" Checked="CheckBoxChecked" />
  <checkBox Name="Left" Content="(F)" Unchecked="CheckBoxUnChecked" Checked="CheckBoxChecked" />
  <Label Content="{Binding Path=Student.Name}" />
</stackPanel>
```

If i select the checkbox with content = (M) and having Label content = "Sam", I want to check other checkbox with content = (F) and having Label content = "Lucie".

Can you please provide me sample code for this ?

Thanks

Comment: your question is unclear. what do you need to do? Besides, do not use event-based programming in WPF. remove the Checked and Unchecked event handlers and bind the `IsChecked` property of the Checkboxes to a data state boolean property in your Model or ViewModel.

Comment: When i get the data from database, here is how, it will showup on the screen:

Comment: still unclear. under what circumstances will the checkbox be checked? and under what circumnstances will the Label change? I do not understand what you're saying.

Comment: (M) (F) Sam   (M) (F) Lucie  (M) (F) Rob etc.... Now when i check (M) for Sam, it should also check the (F) Lucie.

Comment: WPF is not Silverlight... which do you mean?  You've listed two eventhandlers in your code, but you don't include their definitions - what is their purpose?  Also, your Xaml is hardcoding data into the checkboxes, so it's not clear what the relevance of the database is to the question.  Finally: do you really mean that you want both checkboxes to be set to the *same* value of `IsChecked`?

Comment: @Dan this guy has no idea what he's after S:

Comment: Then again you have 2 UIElements with the same `Name="Left"`. That shouldn't even compile.

Comment: @user1054625 I don't think anybody can help you unless you explain your needs better. Also, [What have you Tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The checkboxes shouldn't have the same Name.

You need binding and an IValueConverter:

```
<stackPanel Name="StudentDetails">
  <checkBox Name="Left" 
            Content="(M)" 
            IsChecked="{Binding Student.Name, Converter={StaticResource StudentCheckedConverter}, ConverterParameter="M"}" />
  <checkBox Name="Left" 
            Content="(F)" 
            IsChecked="{Binding Student.Name, Converter={StaticResource StudentCheckedConverter}, ConverterParameter="F"}" />
  <Label Content="{Binding Student.Name}" />
</stackPanel>
```

And the IValueConverter looks like:

```
public class StudentCheckedConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if ("M".Equals(parameter))
                return "Sam".Equals(value);
            if ("F".Equals(parameter))
                return "Lucie".Equals(value);
            throw new Exception("Unknown parameter or value");
        } 

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
}
```

Also, you need to expose StudentCheckedConverter in the XAML's resources, but i figure a tad bit of googling would do you some good.

Comment: Let me explain little bit better:

Comment: <stackPanel Name="StudentDetails">
  <checkBox Name="Male" Content="(M)" Unchecked="CheckBoxUnChecked" Checked="CheckBoxChecked" />
  <checkBox Name="Female" Content="(F)" Unchecked="CheckBoxUnChecked" Checked="CheckBoxChecked" />
  <Label Content="{Binding Path=Student.Name}" />
</stackPanel>

Comment: I am checking the checkboxes at runtime using database values. Now when the user clicks on "Male" - "Sam" checkbox then i want to automatically check the "Female" - "Lucie" checkbox. Probabilly one way to do this is - using Tag property of checkbox. Can we figure it out how we can do the same task using Tag property ?

Comment: Don't use the tag property.  If you want to check both boxes when the user clicks on one, you could try a trigger or a databinding between the two boxes.